# compare two string columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare sets of key words in consecutive rows in pandas: to make it easier, i created a column `df['next_row'] = df.key_words.shift(-1).`
Here is the df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer' : [1,1,2,2],
"key_words":[['oil change'], ['oil change', 'filter'], ['leak'], ['leak', 'filter']]}
```

if I try `df['next_row'].isin(df.key_words)`
I get error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I understand that I cannot compare lists and should use strings instead.
I turned next_row into string:

```
df.next_row = df.next_row .str.join('|')
```

now if I try

```
df.key_words.str.contains(df['next_row'])
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How do I perform row by row comparison so the **output** would be something like:

```
df['word_match'] = ['oil change', nan, 'leak', nan]
```

Comment: groupby shift + intersection

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a list of words that only show repeated occurrences from within a customer grouping, as requested.

```
customer_lists = df.groupby('customer')['key_words'].apply(list)
word_match = []

for cust in customer_lists:
    word_match.extend(list(set.intersection(*map(set,cust))))

print(word_match)
```

Comment: wouldn't this compare all key words? where I need to compare 2 consecutive rows only.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this to your needs. There are going to be NaNs, and so you might want to take care of that too.

```
 def compare(df):
     for val in df.key_words:
          if isinstance(df.consecutive,list):
              if val in list(df.consecutive):
                  return 'in'
              else:
                  return 'not in'
          elif isinstance(df.consecutive,float): #you might want to check for NaNs here
              continue

 df.apply(compare,axis=1)
```